# Bypassing new user restrictions?

Tags: support

Look at revision 4 of [this question](https://superuser.com/posts/921411/revisions). How was the user (with only 1 rep) able to insert images? (He [claims](https://superuser.com/questions/921411/paged-pool-memory-leak-in-windows-8-1#comment1247074_921411) a mod has granted him image posting privileges.)

Looks like he copied over the stack.imgur.com links from his original cs.SE post, but shouldn't new user restrictions have prevented him from inserting `![][]` markup?

(Associated puzzler: cs.SE seems to have the same privilege levels as SU, so how was he in his very [first revision](https://cs.stackexchange.com/posts/43080/revisions) itself able to insert images there?)

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, so can someone point out what that is?

Comment: looks like anyone can upload images http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195927/133693 except on trilogy sites

Comment: @Sathya: Nice, I didn't know that. But how come he was able to add the images here then?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure about that - there was a suggested edit on the 3rd revision tho http://superuser.com/suggested-edits/70236

Comment: @Sathya: Yes, of course I saw rev 3 where Rsya Studios's suggested edit inlined the images. But that doesn't explain rev 4 when the OP himself added more image links.