# New visitors can add images - should we review it

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Is it worth having, within the Review/Tools section (https://superuser.com/tools), thumbnails of all images posted to be reviewed.

I'm not suggesting the image has to be approved first or not, that's up to those who implement it, but I think this is more important now that "new" (low rep) [users can upload images](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/9409/bypassing-new-user-restrictions).

Or are we just hoping that when an image is loaded the 'normal' amount of views it gets will ensure it's flagged any way?

Comment: I'd support this, possibly network-wide. Have you tried asking on Meta.SE?

Comment: No just here @canadianluke but I am not about for a day or 2, can this be migrated?

Comment: Don't know, to be honest

Comment: "now that "new" (low rep) users can upload images" - Dave, [according to the answer Sathya linked to](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/9409/bypassing-new-user-restrictions#comment25416_9409) the new user restrictions are still present on Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Ask Ubuntu and Super User. My question seemed to point to an anomaly that's still not been answered.